# Printing all constraints using DOcplex

Tags: python, optimization, docplex

I am actually running a MILP on Python using DOcplex and it is my very first time using it. It is saying that my model which I ran on Lindo is infeasible. Therefore, I am guessing that I erroneously entered my constraints, but I cannot view them. I used "mdl.print_information()", but it is not helping much. Does anyone know how I can solve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the model to LP format (a human readable LP format), by `Model.export_as_lp()`. You can also export the model to a string in LP format with `Model.lp_string`, to get a complete view of the model.

In addition, this notebook: https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-examples/blob/master/examples/mp/jupyter/infeasible.ipynb
gives hints on how to investigate infeasible models, in particular with the `Relaxer` class.

Knowing which constraint is infeasible (and by how much slack) may lead you to the root cause of the infeasibility.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to identify which constraint was at fault by running the model with a smaller set of data  and using  "mdl.print_information()" each time I added a constraint. Now, I am good to go but I cloned the repository you indicated for my future works.

Comment: Be my guest, these examples are here to help. Let us know if you have questions or remarks on the examples.

Comment: I sure will. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how one can print the dual model?